# I have a problem with Prepositions

Tags: prepositions

I am a beginner in English. I have a problem with how to use proper prepositions.

When I use or read prepositions with words, I am being confused.

I know some usage of prepositions – something like:

> I want to go **to** the shop (this "to" implies "movement")
>
> He is a friend **of** mine (this "of" implies "part")

I can guess their usages with simple sentences. But sometimes, I can't guess why they are used like that. For example:

> He was sentenced **to** jail.
>   He tore it **to** pieces.
>   Do not dispose **of** your ticket.

They are just few part of examples that I don't know.

So how can I know the usage of prepositions?

Comment: Oh thank you J.R. for making my sentence looked more good !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy listen
Of is used to show possession so 
In the sentence..... of shows a possession means ticket is your...

Nd to is not only used for movement it is also used as infinitive means (to + verb)

Comment: Thank you for kind comment :> It was very helpful for me !